# A Game on a Finite Projective Plane

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Two players Oh and Ex alternately choose points of a finite projective plane.
The first player (if any) to make a line in his/her chosen points is the winner.
Using the Erdos-Selfridge theorem, we can see that the game is a draw if the order of the projective plane is 5 or greater.
  The game is a trivial Oh win if the order is 2.  Does Oh win if the order is 3 or 4?

Answer (score 8):

See "Tic-Tac-Toe on a Finite Plane", Maureen T. Carroll and Steven T. Dougherty,
Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 77, No. 4 (Oct., 2004), pp. 260-274. (Preprint here: http://academic.scranton.edu/faculty/carrollm1/tictac.pdf) The second player can force a draw on the 3-by-3 and 4-by-4 projective planes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference, which completely answers the question.  